# Tengo un problema en la ejecución de esta parte del código

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo un problema en la ejecución de esta parte del código.

```
                `public static void cargarLibro(){
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el Id del Libro:");
                    int idLibro = entrada.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("\nIngrese el Nombre del Libro:");
                    String nombre = entrada.nextLine();
                    listaLibros.add(new Libro(idLibro, nombre));
                    System.out.println("\nLibro agregado con éxito");
                }`
```

El problema es que cuando lo ejecuto, y entro en esta opción, la parte de ingresar la ID te lo pide correctamente, pero una vez la ingresas te dice que ingreses el nombre del libro pero no deja escribir nada ya que aparece libro ingresado con éxito en lugar de dejarme escribir el nombre del libro.

[image: Aquí está una captura de lo que pasa al ejecutarlo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(asumo que estas utilizando un `Scanner`) prueba cambiar el método `nextLine()` por el metodo `next()`, quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void cargarLibro(){
                System.out.println("Ingrese el Id del Libro:");
                int idLibro = entrada.nextInt();
                System.out.println("\nIngrese el Nombre del Libro:");
                String nombre = entrada.next();
                listaLibros.add(new Libro(idLibro, nombre));
                System.out.println("\nLibro agregado con éxito");
            }
```

Otra alternativa para leer una frase(teniendo en cuenta los espacios) es incorporar una llamada al metodo `nextLine()` de nuestro `Scanner` para limpiar el buffer :

```
    public static void cargarLibro(){
                System.out.println("Ingrese el Id del Libro:");
                int idLibro = entrada.nextInt();
                System.out.println("\nIngrese el Nombre del Libro:");
                entrada.nextLine();
                String nombre = entrada.nextLine();
                listaLibros.add(new Libro(idLibro, nombre));
                System.out.println("\nLibro agregado con éxito");
            }
```

Usando `next()`  devolverá lo que viene antes de un espacio, `nextLine()` mueve automáticamente el escáner hacia abajo después de devolver la línea actual.

Comment: Si, estoy utilizando un Scanner. Si hago eso que tu me dices, cuando escriba el nombre de un libro solo tendrá una palabra. Si no uso el nextLine() ¿cómo hago para que guarde una o más palabras sin que me de ese error?

Comment: Ahi puse la alternativa de "limpiar" el scanner.

Comment: En parte si funcionó, pero no guarda la primer palabra, las demás si. ¿Existe alguna solución para eso?

Comment: Ahi esta brian! acabo de probar la ultima actualizacion y pude ingresar mi nombre completo con espacios, Intentalo. (Limpie el buffer con nextLine() en vez de next())

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void cargarLibro() {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese el Id del Libro:");
        int idLibro = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el Nombre del Libro:");
        String nombre = entrada.next();
        listaLibros.add(new Libro(idLibro, nombre));
        System.out.println("Libro agregado con éxito");
    }
```

El problema básicamente es que estas haciendo un doble salto de linea, en ese caso la instrucción o método next(); toma esa nueva linea como el nombre del libro, en este caso vacía como y continua con la ejecución del programa.

Simplemente elegir en utilizar el System.out.println(); o System.out.print("\n);
saludos.